# Properties missing from `APP` property of `application-name/config/environment`

Tags: ember.js, ember-cli

Say this is my `application-name/config/environment`

```
/* jshint node: true */

module.exports = function(environment) {
  var ENV = {
    modulePrefix: 'app-name',
    environment: environment,
    rootURL: '/',
    locationType: 'auto',

    pageTitle: {
      separator: ' - ',
      // we want to append the nested title as suffix
      prepend: false,
      // replace completely replaces the outer title we don't want that
      replace: false,
    },

    EmberENV: {
      FEATURES: {
        // Here you can enable experimental features on an ember canary build
        // e.g. 'with-controller': true
      },
      EXTEND_PROTOTYPES: {
        // Prevent Ember Data from overriding Date.parse.
        Date: false
      }
    },

    APP: {
      // Here you can pass flags/options to your application instance
      // when it is created
    },

    i18n: {
      defaultLocale: 'en',
    },
  };

  if (environment === 'test') {
    // Testem prefers this...
    ENV.locationType = 'none';

    // keep test console output quieter
    ENV.APP.LOG_ACTIVE_GENERATION = false;
    ENV.APP.LOG_VIEW_LOOKUPS = false;

    ENV.APP.rootElement = '#ember-testing';
    ENV.APP.API_HOST = 'http://dev.api.appname.com';
  }
  else if (environment === 'production') {

  }
  else {
    ENV.APP.API_HOST = 'http://dev.api.appname.com';
  }

  return ENV;
};
```

> It's pretty much the default generated one, except there is an `API_HOST` in the `APP` sub property in dev & test mode.

Say in a random module I do this

```
import ENV from 'application-name/config/environment';
console.log(ENV.APP.API_HOST);
```

What I expect is the value put in `.APP.API_HOST` to logged, except I see undefined... If I log `ENV.APP` this is what i see

[image]

> note the application name has been removed.

However checking the global object works?

```
console.log(ApplicationName.API_HOST);
```

Now I do not want to access the global object, because it's kinda hacky. It's 2017 and we have es modules now...

### What I've tried

1. made sure I used the right environment, we haven't tried prod yet, because we don't have a prod build...
2. [This specific plugin](https://github.com/gmurphey/ember-config-service), only to get the same result
3. I did ask this question on the help channel on the Ember slack, but I didn't quite have that much success there `:/`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When ember-cli builds your app, it url encodes the config object in a meta field in the HTML, if you have a service worker that fetches the index.html and caches it, when ever you update your `environment/config.js` it'll go in a new index.html

One thing that can prevent you from seeing changes is when your service worker caches your index.html, this is the problem I had.

Answer (score 0):

I noticed you added the values in the `test` environment. just move them to the `development` environment.

Comment: for development final else block will be execued

Comment: I appreciate your input Joe, but @kumkanillam is right.

Also it ended up being my service worker config, as mentioned in my answer